# Dynamically load files from the server to spring boot jar

Tags: xml, spring-boot, jar

I have a spring boot application where I use a target jar to run the application on the Linux server. My application needs some configuration XML files in order to run the application. Currently, i have just copied those XML files into my project. But I am trying to dynamically copy the XML files to my jar file whenever I execute the jar. I tried adding calling the addFiles function above the main call of spring boot application but it did not work. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;


 class HadoopConfiguration {
public void addFiles() {
    File source1 = new File("/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml");
    File source2 = new File("/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml");
    File source3 = new File("/etc/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml");

    File dest1 = new File("core-site.xml");
    File dest2 = new File("hdfs-site.xml");
    File dest3 = new File("hbase-site.xml");

    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(source1, dest1);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source2, dest2);
        FileUtils.copyFile(source3, dest3);
        System.out.println("In here");  
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```